# Find doesn't work with recursion?

Tags: shell, find

I ran the command below and notice it will only did the mod on the first level(SubDir*) on the finding and not the subsequence (ChildSubDir*). I wanted to ask if it is possible to go recursion on the finding and execute with chmod?

### Command ran:

```
find ./to/path/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

### Directories:

```
DirsRoot
  |-->SubDir1
  |    |-->ChildSubDir1
  |             |-->OtherFile1
  |-->SubDir2
  |    |-->ChildSubDir2
  |             |-->OtherFile2
  |-File1
  |-File2
```

Comment: By the way -- if instead of `-exec chmod` you use the default print behavior, do you see that doing the same thing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it did list all it seems. So this mean that the exec didn't perform to all listed directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chmod recursivelly without the need of find. It has the `-R` flag.
Something like:

```
$ cd ./to/path
$ chmod -R 777 *
```

This will `chmod` all files.

If you want to chmod only directories, the command is:

```
find /to/path -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

More details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-chmod-all-directories-except-files-recursively/91966)

Comment: I only need to change directories permission.

Comment: I´ve edited. The given post has the solution.

Comment: it still didn't go recursively haizz

Answer (score 1):

I use below command, and it works.

```
find /to/path/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```